# In PySpark, why does dataframe aggregation work better than the same aggregation in-query on a Kerberized source table?

Tags: pyspark, kerberos

I'm operating on a multinode cluster with Cloudera distro, Spark 2.1.0, whose hive partitions are Kerberized. My query is moderately complex (three tables with two nested subqueries of successive aggregation), and I've been stymied by a GSSException when I run the aggregation steps in SQL before writing to a PySpark dataframe. Operations on the dataframe take between 30 and 45 minutes, and attempts to cache or write the dataframe to parquet invoke the full lineage, complete with Kerberos warnings:

```
18/08/21 19:58:48 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:our_user (auth:KERBEROS) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
18/08/21 19:58:48 WARN kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: KMS provider at [https://funaddress123.next.oururl.domain:12345/zzz/zz/] threw an IOException [org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]!!
```

At the advice of one of our engineer's, I took the aggregation out of SQL and instead read the simple query into a PySpark dataframe, aggregating once the dataframe was created. Cache and Parquet took seconds. No PriviledgedActionException or GSSException arose.

Okay, I have a solution. But why on earth does Kerberos care about where I perform my aggregation?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan (`df.explain()` and `EXPLAIN SELECT some_column, some_agg FROM some_table GROUP BY whatever`) between the two methods? Maybe there's some optimization happening on the spark side that isn't happening in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Key part of the error is "No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)"

Have you done `kinit` ? Or otherwise provided `prinaipal` and `keytab` to `spark-submit`?